# Controller is undefined in ui router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I dont understand why TestCntrl is undefined when I run this. I already have an existing controller (MainCntrl) in the parent and now I want the child to have its own controller (TestCntrl).

```
(function() {
  'use strict';
  angular
    .module('app')
      .config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $urlMatcherFactoryProvider) {

        $urlMatcherFactoryProvider.strictMode(false);
        $urlRouterProvider.when('/', '/search'); 
        $urlRouterProvider.when('/search/name', '/search');

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

        $stateProvider
            .state('index', {
              url: '/',
              abstract: true,

              templateUrl: 'app/layout/layout.html',
              controller: 'MainController',
              controllerAs: 'main'

            })

            .state('index.layout', {

                initFactory2: ['initFactory', function(initFactory) {

                    return initFactory.getClasses().then(function(data) {
                        return data.data;
                    });
                }]

              },
              url: 'search',
              views: {

                'form@index': {
                  templateUrl: 'app/partials/form.html',
                  controller: 'TestController as test'
},
                'results@index':{}
              }
            })
})();
```

*TestController*

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .controller('TestController', TestController);

    /** @ngInject */
    function TestController($scope, $stateParams, $state, model,
                             initFactory2) {
        var vm = this;

        vm.$scope = $scope;
    }
 });
```

*Main Controller*

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .controller('MainController', MainController);

    /** @ngInject */
    function MainController($scope, $stateParams, $state, $timeout, model,
                            SearchFactory) {
        var vm = this;
    }
})();
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'TestController' is not a function, got undefined
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.17/ng/areq?p0=TestController&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
```

Comment: Are the parenthesis at the end of the TestController missing from your actual code or is that just a copy-paste error?

Comment: @MatthewGreen I've fixed that . Copy/paste error

Comment: @MatthewGreen youre right. I added it to my code and that did the trick. Feel free to answer and I'll accept as answer.

Comment: If that was actually the issue you may want to roll back your edit so that people can see what the original issue was. Without it the answer looks a little out of place.

Comment: @MatthewGreen ok i've undone my edits. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing your parenthesis at the end of your IIFE on your TestController. That is needed to properly declare it as function to be executed. Without it, your code for the TestController is never called and therefore never instantiated.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is with your *TestController*

```
(function () {
'use strict';

   angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('TestController', TestController);

  /** @ngInject */
  function TestController($scope, $stateParams, $state, model, initFactory2) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.$scope = $scope;
   }
});
```

just, try reversing the order

```
(function () {
 'use strict';
  /** @ngInject */
  var TestController = function TestController($scope, $stateParams, $state, model, initFactory2){
    var vm = this;
    vm.$scope = $scope;
  };
  angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('TestController', TestController);
});
```